# Обрезать изображение с уменьшением средствами PHP

Tags: php, изображения

Пытаюсь сделать миниатюру изображения на `PHP`. Но существующие примеры или обрезают картинку сразу до нужных размеров, или просто ресэмплируют ее с сохранением пропорций, или в целом сжимают со всеми искажениями. Мне же необходим вариант, когда изображение уменьшается по меньшей стороне с сохранением пропорций, а когда оно уже уменьшено обрезается, чтобы быть нужного размера.

Код, который уменьшает с сохранением пропорций по меньшей стороне:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
$filename = 'image.jpg';

$width = 480;
$height = 320;

list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($filename);    
$ratio_orig = $width_orig/$height_orig;

if ($width/$height < $ratio_orig) {
   $width = $height*$ratio_orig;
} else {
   $height = $width/$ratio_orig;
}

$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);

imagejpeg($image_p, null, 100);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ найден мною же, вдруг кому-то пригодится. Код уменьшает изображение по меньшей стороне, а потом обрезает изображением по краям, для получения нужных размеров. Вот работающий код:

```
<?php
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg('footer.jpg');

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

$thumb_width = 480;
$thumb_height = 320;

$width = imagesx($image);
$height = imagesy($image);

$original_aspect = $width / $height;
$thumb_aspect = $thumb_width / $thumb_height;

if ( $original_aspect >= $thumb_aspect )
{
   $new_height = $thumb_height;
   $new_width = $width / ($height / $thumb_height);
}
else
{
   $new_width = $thumb_width;
   $new_height = $height / ($width / $thumb_width);
}

$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor( $thumb_width, $thumb_height );

imagecopyresampled($thumb, $image, 0 - ($new_width - $thumb_width) / 2, 0 - ($new_height - $thumb_height) / 2, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

imagejpeg($thumb, null, 100);
?>
```

Оригинал ответа: [EngSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1856049/8170192)